# Backbone.relational losing reference to submodels after save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, models, backbone-relational

I'm using backbone relational and have a big app with a lot of nested models. let's say that we have a backbone relational model "bar" that have a has_many relation to a "foo" model. The problem is that when i'm using sub views that way :

```
new blablaView({model: this.model.getFoo()});
```

Everything works fine in the first time but after saving the bar model with :

```
this.model.save();
```

the reference to the foo model in blablaview is lost and changes that are made to the foo model are not applied to the bar model. Is that a way to keep references to sub models after saving ??

Comment: are you posting the save to the data. like api? model has to be permanently saved right?

Comment: Yes i'm saving the data with an API. In fact i have a save button and i launch the save workflow when it's clicked.